# change image size with availHeight and availWidth of javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, attributes, resize

i am new in this forum, i actually just signed in.

I have an index file which includes only one  tag.

this is my code

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>


<script>

h=screen.availHeight;
w=screen.availWidth;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" align="center">
    <img id="image" src="images/last.png" alt="starting"                               onmouseover="this.src='images/first.png';" 
    onmouseout="this.src='images/last.png';"  usemap="#map"/>  

    <map name="map">
        <area shape="rect" coords="13,250,455,450" alt="shops" href="">
        <area shape="rect" coords="675,310,1080,390" alt="eshop" href="/opencart/upload">
    </map>
</div>
```

---

what i want to do is change the size of the image according to the visitor's screen size.
i know that availHeight and availWidth return the height and width of the screen which the browser uses. i want to save the returned values in the variables h and w and then parse these variables inside the html  tag as height=h and width=w

can you help me build my function please and make this work?

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: actually the screen's size would be just that, the screen size. Are you sure you're not looking for `window.width` etc. which gets the size of the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign in width and height in javascript. Put your script just before ending body tag or put in [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
h=screen.availHeight;
w=screen.availWidth;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $img = $('#image');
  $img.width(w);
   $img.height(h);
});
```

OR

```
h=screen.availHeight;
w=screen.availWidth;
$(document).ready(function(){
  img = document.getElementById('image');
  img.style.width = w;
  img.style.height = h;
});
```